# how to generate random number jni in android

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

hi I m trying to convert my `java` code to `c` code for better speed ,

and I want to generate a random number in `c code` using `jni(android)`

in java code,

```
public  int getRandomNumberFor()
    {
        Random random ;
        random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(0xFF);
    }
```

I don't know what code work for `c`

I tried finding example, but unfortunately I don't get it. can any one help me in this.?

Comment: This is unlikely to be faster. The cost of crossing the JNI boundary will probably outweigh any improvements from calling a C method as opposed to a Java method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as using C Programming in NDK :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_imrantestndk_androiddemo_NativeLib_Randomnum
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject this){
    int n;
     n = rand()%100 + 1;

    return n;
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_imrantestndk_androiddemo_NativeLib_Randomnum
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject this){
int random;
randomize();
random = random(100);
return random;
}
```

Comment: +1 yes i tried first one and it's working fine thanks for quick reply .

Comment: i don't tried it but can u tell me witch one is better for use according to speed .

Comment: second one is not working it display error `error: called object 'random' is not a function` it's ok first one is working fine.

Comment: @Youddh : it's depend on C compiler which one u are using currently. second code is turbo c compiler if you have then test it it will work.